# WPF Fonts.GetFontFamilies() caches the list of fonts, how to clear the cache?

Tags: c#, wpf, caching, fonts

In WPF, the following code returns a list of all fonts in the given location:

```
foreach (var fontFamily in Fonts.GetFontFamilies(@"C:\Dummy\Fonts\"))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fontFamily.Source);
}
```

The problem is if you **change** the content of that folder (add or remove a font) and run this code again, it returns the same list (as it is **cached** somewhere internally).

This cache will not be cleared until you **exit** the application!

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour and always make WPF to look into that folder for fonts at that moment?

**NOTE:** The result is the same regardless of *"Windows Presentation Foundation Font Cache 3.0.0.0"* service state is started or stopped. Apparently this specific type of cache is not being handled by the service.

Comment: Does this happen when you run the application in both Debug and Release configurations? I've had a similar problem that was only occurring in Debug mode..

Comment: Yes, it is the same, no matter I run the application in Release/Debug/Within VS/Standalone. Always caching is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you may need to [disable the font cache service](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/aa7b8449-fd93-4f91-a602-26ce1b73dc85), as it may be started automatically when needed.

EDIT:

You may have to get the list of FontFamily objects yourself like so:

```
private static FontFamily CreateFontFamily(string path) {
    Uri uri;
    if (!Uri.TryCreate(path, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
        throw new ArgumentException("Must provide a valid location", "path");

    return new FontFamily(uri, string.Empty);
}

public static IEnumerable<FontFamily> GetNonCachedFontFamilies(string location) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty("location"))
        throw new ArgumentException("Must provide a location", "location");

    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(location);
    if (directoryInfo.Exists) {
        FileInfo[] fileInfos = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.?tf");
        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileInfos)
            yield return CreateFontFamily(fileInfo.FullName);
    }
    else {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(location);
        if (fileInfo.Exists)
            yield return CreateFontFamily(location);
    }
}
```

There may be some issues with the family name, but the above should get you most of the relevant information.

Comment: I am afraid, even with disabled service, the result is the same. 
Apparently that service is only responsible for "Fonts folder" and `Fonts.GetFontFamilies()` uses another caching system.

Comment: @shayan - I've updated my answer to include a sample for getting the associated font families manually, which may or may not work in your case.